# Get value from database to display as history purchase based on username

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I got some problem with my system. The problem is:

How can I get the table data based on username session. Means that, when the user login, they can view the history of the purchase item(using jTable) in their Profile Form. Thanks in advance.

This is my code :

### 1.Profile Form

public class Profile extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
String username;
DefaultTableModel model;
public Profile() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public Profile(String User) {
    username = User;
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void retrieve(){
    DefaultTableModel dth = new Cust_History().getData();

    tblHistory.setModel(dth);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tblHistory = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jtfUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnHistory = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Profile Information");
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 430, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("My Profile", jPanel1);

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    tblHistory.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    tblHistory.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            tblHistoryMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblHistory);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 410, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(55, 55, 55)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Cart History", jPanel2);

    jButton1.setText("Back");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jtfUser.setText("label username");

    btnHistory.setText("Retrieve");
    btnHistory.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnHistoryActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 437, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, `enter code here`javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btnHistory))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jtfUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(52, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jtfUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 272, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)`enter code here`
                .addComponent(btnHistory))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void tblHistoryMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    jtfUser.setText("Hello "+ username + " have a nice day!");
}                                 
enter code here
private void btnHistoryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   retrieve();
}
```

### 2. Cust_History Class

public class Cust_History {

```
String User;

String conString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/softwaredesign";
String username = "root";
String password = "";

//CREATE TABLE
public DefaultTableModel getData(){
DefaultTableModel dth = new DefaultTableModel();
dth.addColumn("Artist");
dth.addColumn("SongTitle");
dth.addColumn("Price");
dth.addColumn("Qty");



    try {
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, username, password);
       Profile pf = new Profile(User);

           //SQL STATEMENT
       String SQL = "SELECT Artist,SongTitle,Price,Qty FROM history WHERE Username LIKE '"+User+"'";

       //PST
       PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
       ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(SQL);

       //LOOP
       while (rs.next()){

           //get value
           String Artist = rs.getString(1);
           String SongTitle = rs.getString(2);
           String Price = rs.getString(3);
           String Qty = rs.getString(4);



           dth.addRow(new String[]{Artist, SongTitle, Price, Qty});

       }

       return dth;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

### Edited Post

Why cant I retrieve user session from Profile Form like this?

```
Profile pf = new Profile(User);
String SQL = "SELECT Artist,SongTitle,Price,Qty FROM history WHERE Username LIKE '"+pf.username+"'";
 PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
       ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(SQL);
```

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOBRi.png)

Comment: it's not clear your problem

Comment: Which part does it not clear?

Comment: the problem is not clear, what are you facing?

Comment: I cant get the table data from (history table). Means that, when user login his id, he can see the previous purchased history based on the (history table).

Comment: history database table*